# Charts, how to format a date/time from external table on X-axis in Views

Tags: datetime, charts

I am using the [Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) Module to bring in some data from an external database.

Have configured a View to display a Chart (using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) Module) of the columns  I require and it works great, except that I can not seem to alter the display of the X-Axis labels, which are showing the format in the database column (epoch date/Unix timestamp). I would like to display label like dd/mm/Y on the X-Axis but can not figure out how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

BTW, I have flagged the Database Column as a Date type in the Data UI, even created an exposed filter to display the chart on date ranges, just that the Chart labels are Unix timestamp.

regards
Darryl